# Checking if parentheses match always saying that they match

Tags: java

I am writing a program where I should check if the opening parenthesis matches the closing one. If it doesn't match, I should display No. Otherwise, I should display yes.

This is the function I wrote, taking the input from the input buffer. However,  I just keep on receiving yes for the second test case, instead of YES NO YES but the other two cases are correct.

```
static String[] braces(String[] values) {
Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
String[] answer = new String[values.length];
for(int i =0; i<values.length;i++){
  char[] crt = values[i].toCharArray();
  for(char c : crt){
    switch(c){
      case '{':
      case '(':
      case '[':
        st.push(c);
        break;
      case '}':
        if(st.isEmpty() || (st.peek() != '{'))
        {
          answer[i]= "NO";
            break;
        }
        st.pop();

      case ')':
        if(st.isEmpty() || (st.peek() != '('))
        {
          answer[i]= "NO";
            break;
        }
        st.pop();


      case ']':
        if(st.isEmpty() || (st.peek() != '['))
        {
          answer[i]= "NO";
            break;
        }
        st.pop();


    }
  }


  if(st.isEmpty() && answer[i].equals("NO") ){
    answer[i]="YES";
    System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = YES due to stack being empty");
  }
  else
  {
    answer[i]="NO";
    System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = NO due to stack being non-empty");
  }
          st.clear();
}
return answer;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it only prints yes, tried to see if it breaks the loops after break and it does

Comment: Beyond that: please use meaningful names. That help th reader understand what is going on.

Comment: why is `answer` a array, do you want a yes or no for each operation? or yes or no for the entire character array?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to practice debugging. What's the shortest string that gives the wrong answer? Trace through your program by hand--in your head, or on paper even--and narrow down the problem. Where does the logic fail? Is it a coding mistake or a logic mistake? A coding mistake means you tried to do the right thing but made a mistake in the code; a logic mistake means your overall algorithm is flawed.

Comment: because I have different test cases, each case has different test, so it should have  YES or NO for each. All I get is NO, at the third case I get no output at all.

Comment: The flow is awkward - consider changing the method name to something like `isBalancedBraces(...)` and return false _as soon as a NO case is encountered_, otherwise return true after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static String[] braces(String[] values) {
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
     String []answer = new String[values.length];
     Boolean isCorrect = false;

    for(int i =0; i< values.length;i++)
     {
         isCorrect = true;
        st.clear();
         char crt[] = values[i].toCharArray();

        for(char c : crt)
         { 
             switch(c)
             {
             case'{':
             case'[':
             case'(':
                 st.push(c);
                 break;

                 case'}':
                 if(st.isEmpty() || st.peek() != '{')
                 {
                     System.out.println("Hellooo");
                     answer[i] ="NO";
                     isCorrect = false;
                 }
                 if(!st.isEmpty()) 
                 {
                    st.pop();
                 }
                 break;

                 case']':
                 if(st.isEmpty() || st.peek() != '[')
                 { 
                     System.out.println("Hell");
                     answer[i] ="NO";
                     isCorrect = false;
                 }
                 if(!st.isEmpty()) 
                 {
                     st.pop();
                }

                 break;

                case')':
                 if(st.isEmpty() || st.peek() != '(')
                 {
                     isCorrect = false;
                 }

                 if(!st.isEmpty()) {

                     st.pop();

                     }

                 break;
             }
         }

         if(isCorrect && st.isEmpty())

         {
             answer[i] = "YES";
             System.out.println("Hello");
         }else answer[i] = "NO";
     }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `stack.firstElement()` to `stack.peek()`, you need the stack top instead of the first element. (`firstElement` is not a `Stack` method)

Comment: I receive the same output

Comment: @Werokk As that other guy said, when you find a string which is *not* match you should immediately break out the loop and check next string.

Answer (score 1):

The great secret of StackOverflow is that it's not actually full of gurus who look at your code the way Neo looks at The Matrix. It's just people examining how your programs runs.

You can do this yourself, and the most ancient and trivial way is through so-called "print debugging".

In short, you just add print statements that prints what your code is doing, and then you follow along and compare it to what you think it *should* be doing. Here's your code with such print statements added:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  static String[] braces(String[] values) {
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
    String[] answer = new String[values.length];
    for(int i =0; i<values.length;i++){
      char[] crt = values[i].toCharArray();
      boolean an = false;
      for(char c : crt){
        switch(c){
          case '{':
          case '(':
          case '[':
            st.push(c);
            break;
          case '}':
            if(st.isEmpty() || (st.firstElement() != '{'))
            {
              answer[i]= "NO";
              System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = NO due to mismatched }");
            }
            st.pop();
            break;

          case ')':
            if(st.isEmpty() || (st.firstElement() != '('))
            {
              answer[i]= "NO";
              System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = NO due to mismatched )");
            }
            st.pop();
            break;

          case ']':
            if(st.isEmpty() || (st.firstElement() != '['))
            {
              answer[i]= "NO";
              System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = NO due to mismatched ]");
            }
            st.pop();
            break;

        }
      }

      if(st.isEmpty()){
        answer[i]="yes";
        System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = YES due to stack being empty");
      }
      else
      {
        answer[i]="no";
        System.out.println("I set answer[" + i + "] = NO due to stack being non-empty");
      }
      st.clear();
    }

    return answer;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] result = braces(new String[] { "(foo}" });
    for(String s : result) System.out.println("The final result is " + s);
  }
}
```

And here's the output, running on the string `(foo}`:

```
I set answer[0] = NO due to mismatched }
I set answer[0] = YES due to stack being empty
The final result is yes
```

Welp, it looks like you're overwriting your previous answer. You should make sure the final test doesn't override the loop's conclusion.

The trivial hack would be to check if `answer[i]` is null, but the better way would be to create a second helper method `boolean braces(String)` that is free to `return true` or `false` at any time, and then simply call that function in a loop in your `braces(String[])`

In any case, this would have been my implementation:

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Test {
  static char flip(char c) {
    switch(c) {
      case '}': return '{';
      case ')': return '(';
      case ']': return '[';
      default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid paren " + c);
    }
  }

  static boolean matched(String value) {
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i=0; i<value.length(); i++) {
      char c = value.charAt(i);
      switch(c) {
          case '{':
          case '(':
          case '[':
            st.push(c);
            break;

          case '}':
          case ')':
          case ']':
            if (st.isEmpty() || st.peek() != flip(c)) {
              return false;
            }
            st.pop();
            break;
      }
    }
    return st.isEmpty();
  }

  static String[] braces(String[] values) {
    String[] result = new String[values.length];
    for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
      result[i] = matched(values[i]) ? "yes" : "no";
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = new String[] { "}", "{}", "{()}", "asdf", "", "{[", "{[[([])]]}", "((foo))" };
    String[] actual = braces(input);
    String[] expected = new String[] { "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes" };
    for(int i=0; i<actual.length; i++) {
      if(!actual[i].equals(expected[i])) {
        System.out.println("Failed: " + input[i] + " should have been " + expected[i]);
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("OK");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, i've been trying for hours with print statements and so on before posting it here, I deleted all the system out print before asking help because i can't figure out where is the problem

Comment: That's great! You'd be amazed at how many people don't even consider it. You should have a look at your print statements and see if they support the same conclusion, and if they don't, what additional information you could have added.

Comment: Your print statements actually helped me a lot, but I can't figure out where it overrides the stack even after clear it

Comment: The stack isn't overridden, it's just that you assign `yes` if the stack is empty afterwards *even when* you have already determined that the answer is `no`. You can check if you have already determined that the answer is `no` before you assign `yes` to it.

Comment: tried using if(st.isEmpty() || answer[i] != "NO"){
        answer[i]="YES";} but it gives me the same output, I am confused

Comment: That's close, but with two issues: 1. You need both (`&&`) and not either (`||`) to be true, and 2. Java requires you to use `.equals` to compare strings, e.g. `"NO".equals(answer[i])` (or `answer[i].equals("NO")` but this will cause a NullPointerException if `answer[i]` is still `null`)

Comment: Tried using it, but the testcase 2 and 3 would still be wrong. for some receive the output should be NO-YES-YES-YES-NO-NO but I get NO-NO-YES-NO-NO-NO

Comment: Do you know which string it's failing for?

Comment: To be honest no, I can't figure out where the problem is:
testcase 2 
{[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}}
output should be
YES
NO
YES
but I get all NO

Comment: By adding more print statements showing what gets pushed/popped, I found that `firstElement()` doesn't return what you'd expect: it returns the bottom element (first-in-last-out element) instead of the top one (first-in-line to be popped element). @zhh below was right in that it should be using `peek`

Comment: I did that before but it didn't work, now it did work but for case 1 and 3. Test 2 still failed with all YES instead of YES NO YES

Comment: Applying one fix and still getting the wrong answer doesn't mean the fix was wrong. In this case there are multiple bugs, and you'd have to fix all of them. I don't know why you're getting three yes's though, I get `yes no yes`. Did you forget to replace `||` with `&&`?

Comment: Yes I did replace it. Even tried to break the switch after popping but still no matching results. I'll edit the initial code with what i've got now

Comment: 1. Move the `break;`s back to where you had them (otherwise it'll fall through and start running the next `case` branch, 2. Replace `if(st.isEmpty() && answer[i].equals("NO") ){` with `if(st.isEmpty() && !"NO".equals(answer[i])){` since you're now checking that it *is* instead of *isn't* "no"

Comment: changing those all the test would fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178099/discussion-between-werokk-and-that-other-guy).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    static final Map<Character, Character> PARENS;
    static final Set<Character> CLOSING_PARENS;
    static {
        PARENS = new HashMap<>();
        PARENS.put('{', '}');
        PARENS.put('[', ']');
        PARENS.put('(', ')');
        CLOSING_PARENS = new HashSet<>(PARENS.values());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        print(braces("(foo}","[]","()","{}","[{}]","([{}])","[[]]"));
        print(braces("[","]","][","[{]}"));

        // test case 2 ...

        print(braces("{[()]}","{[(])}","{{[[(())]]}}"));

        // ... prints YES NO YES  ...
    }

    static void print(String ... values){
        for(String str : values){
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static String [] braces(String ... values) {
        return Arrays.stream(values)
                .map(Test::isBalanced)
                .map(b -> b ? "YES" : "NO")
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[values.length]);
    }

    static boolean isBalanced(String token){

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for(char c : token.toCharArray()){

            if (PARENS.keySet().contains(c)){

                stack.push(c);

            } else if(CLOSING_PARENS.contains(c)){

                if(stack.isEmpty() || !PARENS.get(stack.pop()).equals(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.isEmpty();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to make the following changes

1. Replace `firstElement()` with `peek()` in all cases
2. remove the following statement from the first two cases

   ```
         stack.pop();
         break;
   ```

   3. check if stack is empity at the last case

   if(!stack.isEmpty())

**corrected code:**

```
public class ParenMatch{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] str = { "{}[](){[}]","{[()]}{[(])}{{[[(())]]}}","", "}][}}(}][))][](){()}()({}([][]))[](){)[](}]}]}))}(())(([[)"}; 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(braces(str)));
    }

public static String[] braces(String[] values)
{
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    String[] isCorrect = new String[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        char[] crt = values[i].toCharArray();
        boolean an = false;
        for (char c : crt)
        {
            switch(c)
            {
                case '{':
                case '(':
                case '[':
                    stack.push(c);
                    break;
                case '}':
                    if (stack.isEmpty() || (stack.peek() != '{'))
                    {
                        isCorrect[i] = "NO";
                    }
                    //stack.pop();
                    //break;

                case ')':
                    if (stack.isEmpty() || (stack.peek() != '('))
                    {
                        isCorrect[i] = "NO";
                    }
                    //stack.pop();
                    //break;

                case ']':
                    if (stack.isEmpty() || (stack.peek() != '['))
                    {
                        isCorrect[i] = "NO";
                    }
                    if(!stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.pop();
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (stack.isEmpty())
        {
            isCorrect[i] = "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            isCorrect[i] = "no";
        }
        stack.clear();
    }

    return isCorrect;
}
}
```

**input:**

```
String[] str = { "{}[](){[}]","{[()]}{[(])}{{[[(())]]}}","", "}][}}(}][))][](){()}()({}([][]))[](){)[](}]}]}))}(())(([[)"};
```

**output:**

[yes, yes, yes, no]

Comment: It wont pass any test if I make those changes

Comment: can you put your input values?

Comment: 2
{}[]()
{[}]

3
{[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}}

6
}][}}(}][))]
[](){()}
()
({}([][]))[]()
{)[](}]}]}))}(())(
([[)

Comment: It's weird cause test 1 and 3 work. Just test 2 doesn't :3 {[()]} {[(])} {{[[(())]]}}

Comment: can you check now, i have tested .

Comment: @Werokk i have  corrected and tested all your cases, please check now.  copy and paste the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178100/discussion-between-melaku-and-werokk).